# Why does code fail to replace space with underscore

Tags: python

Hi please can someone explain why the underscore in this code fails to show when printed. Thank you.

```
names = ["Joey Tribbiani", "Monica Geller", "Chandler Bing", "Phoebe Buffay"]
usernames = []
for name in names:
    name.lower().replace(" ", "_")
    usernames.append(name)

print(usernames)
```

Output

*['Joey Tribbiani', 'Monica Geller', 'Chandler Bing', 'Phoebe Buffay']*

Comment: It does. It just doesn't do anything to the *list*.

Answer (score 1):

It was because you were not assigning the processed data to variable `name`.

```
names = ["Joey Tribbiani", "Monica Geller", "Chandler Bing", "Phoebe Buffay"]
usernames = []
for name in names:
    name=name.lower().replace(" ", "_")
    usernames.append(name)

print(usernames)
```

Comment: if the doubt is solved , you can choose this as the answer .So others won't have to spend time for solving